# Foreign languages words in a text

Tags: ms-word, foreign-keys

I've a french text with some words in english and I want to find those words and highlight all of them at once. Is there any program that can help me do that? Is it possible to do this with any other foreign language?

I'm using microsoft Word.

Answer (score 0):

Word can do this IF the English words are formatted with the English language (and the rest in the French language). In that case, Word's FIND functionality advanced options are able to filter so that the language formatting is searched (instead of text).